# 401 Authentication issue using twitter api with Get Method (oAuth)

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I want to search microblogs from twitter using 
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.xml
using following header to authenticate the request.

```
{Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="NjM0NTU3NjkwODQ1NjI1MDAw",
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1320201086",
 oauth_consumer_key="Key Goes Here",
 oauth_token="Token goes here",
 oauth_signature="D%2FEWfy3qEr5QiEzSvtcYhBDs864%3D",
 oauth_version="1.0"
}
```

but it give me 401 Authentication failed.
Can anybody help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into using a pre-made library to handle the Twitter API calls, or, at the very least, OAuth.

In my opinion, it will not be worth your time to work through the many steps required for OAuth request signing.

There are many libraries available (list swiped from dev.twitter.com with inactive projects omitted):

- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/)
- [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock)
- [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)
- [OAuth-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/)
- [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/)

Full disclosure: I am the author of [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/).

Comment: Hi ricky. thanks for your reply. I read ur suggestions but i am still not geting it. Can u please give me a code example for searching profiles and microblogs and display on ur page.